# Date Picker Not Displayed When Clicking On Calendar

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have input fields which are date pickers and at present, work fine when you click in the field.  But I have been asked that the calendar should also display when a user clicks on the calendar but this is the bit I cant get to work.

I am using a textbox extension and my code is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CalandarTextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string prefix, string name, object value, object htmlAttributes)
    {

        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

        string template = "";
        template += "<div class=\"input-group input-group-IE7\">";
        template += "   <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\" {2}";
        template += "   <div class=\"input-group-addon input-group-addon-IE7\"><i class=\"{3}\"></i></div>";
        template += "</div>";
        MvcHtmlString TextBox = new MvcHtmlString(
            String.Format(template, name, value, tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal).Replace("<input ", " "), prefix)
            );

        return TextBox;
    }
```

My code in my view for these fields is then:

```
template.Nvc.Add("[!FromDate]",  Html.CalandarTextBox("glyphicon glyphicon-calendar", "FromDate", fromDateValue, new { @class = "form-control" }).ToHtmlString());
```

And finally my Javascript for the field is:

```
    $("#FromDate").click(function () {
        $("#Months").val(0);
    });

    $("#FromDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
```

As I said the above, displays the calendar when I click on the input field but NOT if I click on the calendar at the end of the input field.

How do I do this.

Comment: From the top of my head: you're binding the calendar to the input box. With dev tools try to see if the "calendar" thingy has a class you can leverage to bind a click on it.

Comment: Just show us the rendered content for the datapicker input you are trying to target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix

```
$("#FromDate").datepicker({
                        showOn: "button",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        buttonImage: "../../images/calendar.png",
                        buttonImageOnly: true,
                        buttonText: "Select date",
                        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
                    });

$("#ToDate").datepicker({
                    showOn: "button",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    buttonImage: "../../images/calendar.png",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    buttonText: "Select date",
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
                });
```

Html

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnPicker">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>

            </div>
            <!-- /input-group -->
        </div>
```

Javascript

$(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

```
    $('#btnPicker').click(function () {
        //alert('clicked');
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
    });
});
```